# Excel Web Scraper - Password Protected Website

Tags: vba, excel, passwords

I would like to access a website called valueline, 
Link:

> https://jump.valueline.com/login.aspx

and I would like to login because some of the research is password protected. I tried saving my password onto Internet Explorer which seems to log me in every time I use the above link; however, when I want to access a different page, it signs me out. I would like to scrape data from this page for example, Link:

> https://research.valueline.com/research#sec=company&sym=AAPL

I can't seem to get the login to work, but the web scraping part works fine. You can make a trial account to test it out.

Here is my code so far. Thanks for any help/advice.

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim ie As Object
Set Rng = Range("A5:A5")


Set Row = Range(Rng.Offset(1, 0), Rng.Offset(1, 0).End(xlDown))

    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With ie
    .Visible = True

    For Each Row In Rng
    'Login Website
    .navigate "https://jump.valueline.com/login.aspx?"
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))

    'Research Page
    .navigate "https://research.valueline.com/research#sec=company&sym=" & Range("A" & Row.Row).Value

    Do
    DoEvents
    Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Dim doc As HTMLDocument
    Set doc = ie.document
    While ie.readyState <> 4
    Wend

    'Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:25"))

    Dim tblName As Object
    Dim span As Object
    Dim price As String


    On Error Resume Next
    'Inserts the Name

    'Last Price

    Range("B" & Row.Row).Value = doc.getElementsByClassName("alignLeft")(9).innerText

    'Dividend yield
    Range("C" & Row.Row).Value = doc.getElementsByClassName("alignLeft")(13).innerText
    Range("D" & Row.Row).Value = doc.getElementsByClassName("alignLeft")(14).innerText

    Range("E" & Row.Row).Value = doc.getElementsByClassName("rank-text")(0).innerText
    Range("F" & Row.Row).Value = doc.getElementsByClassName("rank-text")(1).innerText
    Range("G" & Row.Row).Value = doc.getElementsByClassName("rank-text")(2).innerText


    Next Row


   End With
   ie.Quit
```

End Sub

Comment: You have a pro account? If you have ask the support for the api, if not I assume it's not legal what you're trying, read the licence agreement! You know [finance.yahoo.com](https://finance.yahoo.com)? If it hasn't changed it's free(read licence) and has an api and lot's of Excel code in the net.

Comment: I do have a pro account, and it's perfectly legal. They even outline in the Terms and Conditions that "You may make one offline copy of the Content for your own personal use."

Comment: Then they should provide information about their api, ask the support. Found that [alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10040954/alternative-to-google-finance-api) on SO.

Comment: I updated my answer, but it is not working yet (I need to rethink on timing as it fills the fields with the same data). Now you have to type the first value by hand and click ok in MsgBox after page has finished loading. All following searches are done automatic. Any news from support?

Comment: No word on them yet; oh, it looks like the paste messed up for the if else statement. It should be 'FirstSearchDone = true'. Also I'm not too sure what the if statement parameter does for FirstSearch Done, but I'm really new to VBA so it might just be me reading it wrong. Does it automatically assume that you are checking if its true?

Comment: A condition can be `True` or `False` it's  a boolean. So no need to compare `If True = True`, just `If True`.

Comment: FirstSearchDone just indicates, that you have done the manual input. You can handle the first element of `rng`seperate outside the loop, but then you can't use `For Each` (or have to define a new range) and should extract the `Range`settings to a method to stay DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, but if the website changes (e.g. addtional alignLeft class element in front of the 9th) the code won't work as expected. You should add additional checks if the site has changed its code.
That's why I suggest you to use an API, that is independent of the websites code.

This code still has some uglyness (e.g. the check for document completed by using `On Error Resume Next`), but has improved (read the comments) and should work.

**Not working properly yet! WIP**

```vb
Sub Macro1()
Dim ie As Object
Dim rng As Excel.Range  'Always declare all vars
Dim row As Excel.Range
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook 'Don't rely on implicit ActiveWorkbook or Sheet, declare!
Dim sh As Excel.Worksheet
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set sh = wb.Worksheets(1)

Set rng = sh.Range("A5:A5")


Set row = sh.Range(rng.Offset(1, 0), rng.Offset(1, 0).End(xlDown))

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With ie
    .Visible = True
    'Login Website
    .navigate "https://jump.valueline.com/login.aspx?"
    'Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05")) 'Don't use Application.Wait
    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until Not ie.Busy And ie.readyState = 4 'Check for busy too, or better use InternetExploreres Withevent DocumentComplete and check for sth. like pDisp.object = ie.object, I will evaluate this soon.
    Dim doc As HTMLDocument

    Set doc = .Document

    If ie.LocationURL <> "https://jump.valueline.com/Loggedon.aspx" Then 'if loggen in ie gets redirected to loggedon.aspx
        doc.getelementbyid("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_LoginControl_txtUserID").Value = "valuelinetester@gmail.com" 'fill login form an submit
        doc.getelementbyid("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_LoginControl_txtUserPw").Value = "Valueline1"
        doc.getelementbyid("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_LoginControl_btnLogin").Click ''click submit, because the forms code uses some strange javascript I don't know what it does. Usuallay you refer to the form direct and submit it or use a Get/Post request.
    Else
        'Already logged in
    End If
    Dim FirstSearchDone As Boolean
    FirstSearchDone = False

    For Each row In rng
    'Research Page
        If FirstSearchDone Then
            .navigate "https://research.valueline.com/secure/research#sec=company&sym=" & row.Value
        Else
            If MsgBox("First search has to be done manually. Please type " & row.Value & _
                " in searchbox and click on result. After Site is loaded click OK.", vbOKCancel) = vbOK Then 'First search has to be done manually
                FirstSearch = True
            Else
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If


        Do
            DoEvents
        Loop Until Not ie.Busy And ie.readyState = 4

        On Error Resume Next ' If IE not ready error occurs and loop starts again
        Do
            Err.Clear 'clear error to detect ie.document set

           'Inserts the Name

            'Last Price
            With sh 'uses explicit sheet instead of former implicit activesheet
                .Range("B" & row.row).Value = doc.getElementsByClassName("alignLeft")(9).innerText

                'Dividend yield
                .Range("C" & row.row).Value = doc.getElementsByClassName("alignLeft")(13).innerText
                .Range("D" & row.row).Value = doc.getElementsByClassName("alignLeft")(14).innerText

                .Range("E" & row.row).Value = doc.getElementsByClassName("rank-text")(0).innerText
                .Range("F" & row.row).Value = doc.getElementsByClassName("rank-text")(1).innerText
                .Range("G" & row.row).Value = doc.getElementsByClassName("rank-text")(2).innerText
            End With
        Loop While Err.Number = 91 'error if ie.document not set



        On Error GoTo 0
        Err.Clear

    Next row

    .Quit
End With
Set ie = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: It looks like the log in script is working great, but after the "Loggedon" page loads and it navigates to the research page, it still seems to not be signed in. I think it seems to be because Internet Explorer doesn't want to redirect with the login information. Is there a way to use the search bar and click the result? I know you did it in the log in page. I'll fiddle with it as well. Thanks for the comments by the way, it really helps.

Comment: I figured out a solution to the timing I think; By simply comparing, lets say, the price, of the last symbol to the next symbol, all we need is a simple while loop to compare them. `While lastSearch = doc.getElementsByClassName("alignLeft")(9).innerText
                Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
            Wend`

Comment: Better compare more elements to be save. I will provide a solution relying on the `DocumentCompleted` events `pDisp` compared to the `ie` object whjich should be save..